# Symfony2 Event_listener not firing

Tags: events, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfont RC5 and I'm trying to get event listener `prePersist` to fire.

In `app/config/config.yml` I have:-

```
services:
   recordmanagement:
      class: FNQITServices\BMBundle\Listener\RecordManagement
      tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

And I created a class `src/FNQITServices/BMBundle/Listener/RecordManagement.php`:-

```
<?php
namespace FNQITServices\BMBundle\Listener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use FNQITServices\BMBundle\Entity\Elections;
use FNQITServices\BMBundle\Entity\People;

class RecordManagement
{
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        `echo "amibeingcalled" > /tmp/test`;

        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        // perhaps you only want to act on some "Product" entity
        if ($entity instanceof Elections) {
            $person = $this->getDoctrine()
                       ->getRepository('FNQITServicesBMBundle:People')
                       ->find(2);

            $entity->setCreator($person);
        }
    }
}
```

But the event is not fired off during an insert. i.e. the file `/tmp/test` is not being created.

- I noticed that there is `kernel.event_listener` and I noticed that this used to be `kernel.listener` a few versions back
- I've tried various combinations of 'tags' attributes in the config.
- I disabled lifecycle annotations that I had in the Elections Entity (incase there was some conflict)
- I've looked in the console logs, events...to try and find any mention of the issue

I'm using Sonata's CRUD. Not sure if that makes any differences.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
services:
recordmanagement:
    class: FNQITServices\BMBundle\Listener\RecordManagement
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist, method: testMethod }
```

and

```
<?php
    namespace FNQITServices\BMBundle\Listener;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
    use FNQITServices\BMBundle\Entity\Elections;
    use FNQITServices\BMBundle\Entity\People;

    class RecordManagement
    {
        public function testMethod(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pretty sure I tried something like this... I ended up creating services.xml under src/ACME/BMBundle/Resources/config and then it seemed to pick up the listener definition. So having it in config.yml was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

maybe that's not the issue but you are using very old symfony version. maybe try at first to upgrade to latest stable (for now 2.0.12)

Comment: just testet it in 2.0.12 with sonata admin it does not work he is right, but preUpdate is fired, but with a wrong changeset

Answer (score 0):

Having the same Problem.

Just testet it the same Way with Symfony 2.0.12 (current version) and sonata and it does not seem to work. I'm using the onFlush Event for my needs now.

It seems that SonataDoctrineORMAdmin is not computing the Changeset right, since every Field is always updated, so you'll have to check that manually.

Comment: can u explain what you did there ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I created services.xml within src/Acme/BMBundle/Resources/config as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="acme_bm.listener" class="ACME\BMBundle\Listener\RecordManagement">
            <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
            <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="prePersist" method="prePersist"/>
        </service>
        <service id="acme_bm.listener2" class="ACME\BMBundle\Listener\RecordManagement">
            <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
            <tag name="doctrine.event_listener" event="preUpdate" method="preUpdate"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

Then I created Listener/RecordManagement.php as follows:-

```
<?php
namespace ACME\BMBundle\Listener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface; 

class RecordManagement 
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container; 
    }


    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
.
.
.
    }
.
.
.
.
}
```